# Calculate the limit of $\frac{\cos x}{(1+\sin x)e^x}$

Tags: limits, continuity

How would I calculate the limit of $\displaystyle\frac{\cos x}{(1+\sin x)e^x}$ as $x$ approaches infinity? I’m trying to use the squeeze theorem, but I don’t get what happens when the denominator equals 0. Also, is this function continuous?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that there is an infinite number of points in which the function diverges, namely $3\pi/2+2k\pi$ and an infinite number of points where the function is zero, the function assumes every value in $\mathbb{R}$ in every interval around $+\infty$, so the limit does not exists.

Comment: That’s what I thought, but WolframAlpha or Geogebra and possibly many others say that the limit is 0.

Comment: You can try in that apps to calculate the limit in $3\pi/2+2k\pi$ with an integer $k$ and you should get $\pm\infty$ from right and from left.

Answer (score 1):

As noticed limit doesn't exist, indeed we can explicitely find two different paths which lead to different limits.

For the first path let consider, for $n\to \infty$

$$x_n= 2\pi n\to \infty$$

then

$$\frac{\cos x_n}{(1+\sin x_n)e^{x_n}}=\frac{1}{e^{2\pi n}}\to 0$$

but for the second path

$$x_n= 2\pi n+\arcsin\left(\frac1{e^{4\pi n}}-1\right)\to \infty$$

we have

$$\frac{\cos x_n}{(1+\sin x_n)e^{x_n}}=
\frac{\cos\left(\arcsin\left(\frac1{e^{4\pi n}}-1\right)\right)}{\left(1+\sin\left(\arcsin\left(\frac1{e^{4\pi n}}-1\right)\right)\right)e^{2\pi n+\arcsin\left(\frac1{e^{4\pi n}}-1\right)}}=$$

$$=\frac{\cos\left(\arcsin\left(\frac1{e^{4\pi n}}-1\right)\right)}{e^{-2\pi n+\arcsin\left(\frac1{e^{4\pi n}}-1\right)}}=\frac{e^{2\pi n}\cos\left(\arcsin\left(\frac1{e^{4\pi n}}-1\right)\right)}{e^{\arcsin\left(\frac1{e^{4\pi n}}-1\right)}}\to \sqrt 2 e^{\frac \pi 2}$$

indeed

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} e^{x}\cos\left(\arcsin\left(\frac1{e^{2x}}-1\right)\right) =\sqrt 2$$

Yes the function is continuous, since we are excluding points with $\sin x=-1$.